# Jquery hover event not firing?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm having some trouble with some jquery code that I have written for my site.

I'm using the [cloudcarousel](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm/) plugin to have a carousel of images on the homepage of a website that I am creating. The html code for the carousel is as follows:

```
    <div id="carousel" style="width:100%; height:100%;overflow:scroll;">
                <img id="sample1image"      alt="sample 1"   class = "cloudcarousel current" src="img/homepage/random1.png" />
                <img id="sample2image"       alt= "sample 2" class = "cloudcarousel left leftrotate" src="img/homepage/random2.png"/>
                <img id="sample3image"     alt = "sample 3" class = "cloudcarousel" src = "img/homepage/random3.png" />
                <img id="sample4image"          alt = "sample 4" class = "cloudcarousel" src = "img/homepage/random4.png" />
                <img id="sample5image"       alt="sample 5" class = "cloudcarousel" src = "img/homepage/random5.png" />
                <img id="sample6image" alt="sample 6"  class = "cloudcarousel right rightrotate" src = "img/homepage/random6.png" />


                <input class = "leftrotate" id="left-but"  type="button" value="" />
                <input class = "rightrotate" id="right-but" type="button" value="" />

                <div class="bubble" id="homepagebubble">
                    <span id="bubbleinnercontainer"><a id="bubbletext" href="#">Sample 1</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And I've initialized my code using the following code in jquery:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#carousel").CloudCarousel({
                xPos : 500,
                yPos : 100,
                xRadius : 400,
                yRadius : -8,
                minScale : 0.8,
                speed : 0.3,
                bringToFront : true,
                buttonLeft : $("input.leftrotate"),
                buttonRight : $("input.rightrotate"),
                altBox : $("#alt-text"),
                titleBox : $("#title-text")
            });
           $('.leftrotate').click(leftRotation);

            $('.rightrotate').click(rightRotation);
         });
```

And here is my leftRotation method:

```
    function leftRotation() {
       $('.bubble').css('display', 'none');

       var nextimage = "";
       var rightimage = "";
       var leftimage = "";
       var nextimageindex = $(currentimage).prev().index();

       rightimageindex = $('.right').index();
       leftimageindex = $('.left').index();
       //increment the indexes
       rightimageindex -= 1;
leftimageindex -= 1;

if (rightimageindex < 0) {
    rightimageindex = rightimageindex + 6;
    //if its out of bounds, then bring it back in range
}
if (leftimageindex < 0) {
    leftimageindex = leftimageindex + 6;
}

rightimage = $('.cloudcarousel').eq(rightimageindex);
leftimage = $('.cloudcarousel').eq(leftimageindex);
$('.right').removeClass('right rightrotate');
$('.left').removeClass('left leftrotate');

rightimage.addClass('right rightrotate');
leftimage.addClass('left leftrotate');


var currentimage = $('.current').attr('id');
currentimage = "#" + currentimage;
if ($(currentimage).prev().index() == -1)//if this is the first image
{
    nextimage = $('.cloudcarousel').eq(5);
    $(currentimage).removeClass('current');
    nextimage.addClass('current');
    $('#bubbletext').text(nextimage.attr('alt'));
} else {

    nextimage = $(currentimage).prev();
    $(currentimage).removeClass('current');
    nextimage.addClass('current');
    $('#bubbletext').text(nextimage.attr('alt'));
}

$('.bubble').fadeIn('slow');
```

}

The div with the class "bubble" represents a box on the homepage whose texts matches the current carousel that is in the front of the carousel, or the "current" image, as determined by the class current in the code. The left and right buttons (id's left-but and right-but) both trigger the correct sequence of events; on click the leftRotation and rightRotation events fire, which causes the classes for current, leftrotate, and rightrotate to shift to the new current, left, and right images, and the text in the bubble changes. However, when I try to attach the same methods to the images in the carousel, the click fires on the images that the method was originally attached to, and only that image; it will not fire on the other images even though the class has changed.

Is it best to not attach an event based on the particular class of an event if the node that class is attached to is going to change? What is a better way to get this event to fire? I've been stumped on this for 2 days now and could really use some help coming up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `$(selector).on()` instead of `$(selector).click()`:

```
// pass in e for e.preventDefault();
$('.leftrotate').on('click', function(e) { leftRotation(e) }); 
$('.rightrotate').on('click', function(e) { rightRotation(e) });
```

jQuery documentation for `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

If you are injecting elements into the DOM, then you'll need to have the event handler called *after* the element has been created:

"Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next."